# Perforce p4v Merge/Integrate freeze after file rename

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm having trouble performing a `merge/integrate` from branch1/sql/ to b2/sql

I performed a rename operation in `p4v` from _1.sql to _2.sql

Made a small change to `_2` file

Submitted changes

Went to submitted changes, and tried to perform a `merge/integrate` on `_2` to the other branch (b2/sql).

The problem is that p4v freezes at that point:

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

BTW, I have the latest version: `Version:   Helix P4V/NTX64/2018.2/1666551`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the generated changelist description, P4V appears to be hopelessly confused and trying to integrate the file into itself rather than between the two different branches you specified.

Easiest fix is to run it from the command line:

```
p4 merge //depot/Engineering/INT-DEV/...@=CHANGE //depot/Engineering/projects/...
```

where `CHANGE` is the small change you're trying to merge (this is easier/safer than specifying the full file path, especially if you're dealing with a file that got renamed in one branch but not the other since it's otherwise easy to mess up entering one of the paths).

If the small change is the only change you've made since the last merge, you can just trust p4 to figure that out automatically and do this very simple command instead:

```
p4 merge //depot/Engineering/INT-DEV/... //depot/Engineering/projects/...
```